# XeTeX kerning with \newunicodechar

Tags: xetex, unicode, kerning

Am using Adobe Garamond Pro and need the two characters ʾ and ʿ that do not exist in that font. I have solved this by rotating ˘ 90 degrees either direction and making these new unicode characters with `newunicodechar`. This way I can type ʿ and ʾ directly in the source code to get the right output. Now, these characters are quite odd and need some adjusted kerning. I want to do this with `\XeTeXinterchartoks`. The problem is that this does not work with the newly created characters. Why is that and is there a workaround?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\setmainfont{Adobe Garamond Pro} %substitute as desired

% make new character
\newunicodechar{ʾ}{\rotatebox[origin=center]{90}{˘}\hspace{-1.2ex}}

% (absurly large) kerning
\XeTeXinterchartokenstate=1
\newXeTeXintercharclass\dia
\XeTeXcharclass `\ʾ=\dia
\newXeTeXintercharclass\el
\XeTeXcharclass `\l=\el
\XeTeXinterchartoks \el \el {\kern 1em}
\XeTeXinterchartoks \dia \el {\kern 1em}


\begin{document}

\Huge
llʾllll
\end{document}
```

[image]

Bonus question: Is there a way to rotate only the glyph ˘ and not the space below it?

Comment: The `\XeTeXinterchartoks` feature works only with actual characters; with `\newunicodechar{<char>}{<tokens>}` XeTeX will never see `<char>` at the processing stage where the feature is applied, because `<char>` has been substituted by `<tokens>`.

Comment: I see. That answers my question but as a comment I can't accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you do `\newunicodechar{<char>}{<tokens>}`, the effect is that `<char>` becomes like a macro and so it disappears before reaching the stage where the `\XeTeXinterchartoks` feature is applied.

You can however work around this by using an expansion for your character that ends with an unused character; here I set U+FEFF (ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\setmainfont{Old Standard} %substitute as desired

\usepackage{graphicx}

% make new character
\newunicodechar{ʾ}{\rotatebox[origin=center]{90}{˘}\hspace{-1.2ex}^^^^feff}

% (absurly large) kerning
\XeTeXinterchartokenstate=1
\newXeTeXintercharclass\dia
\XeTeXcharclass "FEFF=\dia
\newXeTeXintercharclass\el
\XeTeXcharclass `\l=\el
\XeTeXinterchartoks \el \el {\kern 1em}
\XeTeXinterchartoks \dia \el {\kern 1em}


\begin{document}

\Huge
llʾllll
\end{document}
```

The syntax `^^^^feff` is equivalent to typing the character directly (in this case it's better because it shows it). The hexadecimal number `"FEFF` can be used for assigning the character to a class (notice that lowercase is required for the `^^^^` notation, while uppercase must be used for hexadecimal numbers).

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This answers your bonus question only.  In general, there is not an automated fix, since the location of the glyph will, in general, have asymmetrical space above and below it, which can't be formulaically known in advance.  But with a little work, solution can be achieved (whether this was better than what the OP was doing is for you to decide).

To get the item of the same width, place it in a box of the original glyph's width.  To get the horizontal kerning right, I provide `\xrb[offset]{glyph}` to see a boxed version of the rotated glyph, allowing you to determine the proper offset.  Once the proper offset is determined, just use `\rb[offset]{glyph}` with that offset

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{calc}
\fboxsep=-\fboxrule
\newcommand\xrb[2][0pt]{\fbox{\makebox[\widthof{#2}][r]{%
  \raisebox{#1}{\rotatebox{90}{\raisebox{-#1}{#2}}\kern-#1}}}}
\newcommand\rb[2][0pt]{\makebox[\widthof{#2}][r]{%
  \raisebox{#1}{\rotatebox{90}{\raisebox{-#1}{#2}}\kern-#1}}}
\begin{document}
\fbox{'} \xrb[0pt]{'} \xrb[1pt]{'} \xrb[2pt]{'} \xrb[3pt]{'} \xrb[4pt]{'}

Steve\rb[4pt]{'}s test
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. That's a nice and systematic way to go about it it.